# Why does it not notify you when question is put on hold?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, notifications, global-inbox

I find it impossible to track all the questions that I ever asked. If at some point my question is put on hold, why am I not notified to make changes to it unless I go that question directly on each site? Sometimes questions gets flagged without anyone leaving comments thus there is never notification in inbox.

Comment: Getting notified after your question is closed is "re-active", I want to be "pro-active" and get it while it is still [on-hold] to prevent it from going to [closed].

Answer (score -2):

Because we expect the questions you post to have sufficient importance and urgency that you will actively monitor them.

Comment: Though a brilliant answer, this doesn't cover the case where an older question gets put on hold.

Comment: Having said that - the scope of what's on topic/acceptable has changed over the years... so while of limited use it might be nice to be notified a question from 3 years ago was closed... (or indeed locked for historical purposes)

Comment: I understand that it is my responsibility to keep up with my own questions. I just find it impossible to keep a track of everything.

Comment: You've asked six  questions on Stack Overflow.  You can't keep an eye on six questions?  Only one of them has been asked recently.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - OP has accounts on 17 sites. It is not as easy to keep an eye on 17 sites.

Comment: @SaUce: I still think my answer applies.  If you haven't gotten an answer in the first week or two,  knowing whether the question has closed or not doesn't seem like useful information.

Comment: One of the purposes of the on hold introduction was to suggest to users that salvageable questions would be reopened if fixed. A notification would further this.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Six months after the fact?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sorry, I don't understand the meaning of your response. What is happening six months late?

Comment: The on-hold message on open tabs is not ajax-updated either. The user only gets notified of a closure if he _actively_ refreshes the page. Is that the level of participation you expect of users (especially given that comments and answers _are_ monitored by AJAX)?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Add a feature request that tweaks the "This question is now closed... no more answers will be accepted" banner at the top of the page so that it works for all users with a page open on the question, including the OP.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I believe such request already exists

Comment: @EsotericScreenName: Six months after the question is asked.

Comment: @JanDvorak: If you can find it for me, I'll put a bounty on it, so it shows up in the "featured" tab.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The only logically consistent answer regarding "Six months after the fact?" is for the question to go straight to [closed] if old. I don't believe that happens so the hope must be that the OP can still improve it

Comment: I thought that's what the review queues were for.